# "system policy prevents installing the bootloader"

Tags: usb-creator

I am running `usb-creator-gtk`.

After copying files it says: "system policy prevents installing the bootloader".

Why does it say this?  I am not trying to modify my system.  I am creating a bootable USB drive.  I don't understand why modifying a thumb drive would require administrator privileges.

Comment: I found that the `Disks` utility (`gnome-disks`) can be used as a replacement for `usb-creator-gtk` (there is an option called "Restore Disk Image"). This also requires administrator privileges, but I got the sense that it was less buggy than `usb-creator-gtk`. *Just be sure that you select the correct USB device*.

Comment: Or just use the `dd` utility to copy the `.iso` file to the USB device.

Comment: [Why does usb-creator-gtk require root access?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62039/why-does-usb-creator-gtk-require-root-access)

Answer (score 1):

Because the system policy for usb-creator-gtk is set up like that. See the `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/com.ubuntu.usbcreator.policy` file and the `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla` file. Why? I don't know, maybe the usb-creator code is not safe enough, and the program can be used even to modify internal drives. Maybe it is safe, but the creators don't want to risk it, so they chose not to allow modifications without privileges.

If you don't like that, you can override it (of course that process will require root privileges).